# Finding ConvexHull of points

Tags: python, list, scipy

Following array:

```
p = np.array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 9,  0],
       [18,  0],
       [27,  0],
       [36,  0],
       [45,  0],
       [54,  0],
       [63,  0],
       [72,  0],
       [ 0,  9],
       [ 9,  9],
       [18,  9],
       [27,  9],
       [36,  9],
       [45,  9],
       [54,  9],
       [ 0, 18],
       [ 9, 18],
       [18, 18],
       [27, 18],
       [36, 18],
       [ 0, 27],
       [ 9, 27],
       [18, 27],
       [ 0, 36]])
```

When I try to run the example from here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html

```
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(p[:,0], p[:,1], 'o')
for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(points[simplex, 0], points[simplex, 1], 'k-')
```

I get:

[image]

I don't see the convex hull. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Works for me. I did have to change your code from `plt.plot(points[simplex, 0], points[simplex, 1], 'k-')` to `plt.plot(p[simplex, 0], p[simplex, 1], 'k-')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With few modifications on your code, this should work:

```py
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(p[:,0], p[:,1], 'o')
hull = ConvexHull(p)
for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(p[simplex, 0], p[simplex, 1], 'k-')
```

[image]